# Error: Incorrect syntax near (database name)

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc

hi I am getting this error in my Java program. Here  is my query. It is working good in SQL server. but getting

> Error: Incorrect syntax near 'WebApp'.

```
private static final String SERVICES = 
        "SELECT  s.Service_ID  "
            + ",s.[Location_ID]  "
            + ",COALESCE(st.[Service_Type_Name],s.[Service_Name]) AS Service_name "
            + ",st.Service_Type_Name "
            + " FROM    [WebApp].[dbo].[Services]  s join [WebApp].[dbo].[ServiceTypes]  st on s.Service_Type=st.Service_Type_ID "
            + " join WebApp.dbo.Locations l on s.Location_ID=l.Location_ID " 
            + " where s.Deleted=0 " 
            + " ORDER BY Location_ID ";
```

and here is my method it is working fine on ms sql server 2008

```
    public List<MAServiceVO> getAddServices() throws CoopCRSAPIException {
        ArrayList<MAServiceVO> results = new ArrayList<MAServiceVO>();
        MAServiceVO maServiceVO = null;
        log.debug("==========IN VendorDAOimpl.java (service)===========");
        //int serviceID = 0;
        //int prevServiceID = 0;
        try {
            conn = MSSQLDAOFactory.createConnection();
            stmt  = conn.prepareStatement(SERVICES);
//          stmt.setTimestamp(1, startDate);
//          stmt.setTimestamp(2, endDate);

            stmt.execute();
            rs = stmt.getResultSet();

            while (rs.next()) {

                    // create new service
                    maServiceVO = new MAServiceVO();
                    // set service fields
                    maServiceVO.setServiceID(rs.getInt("Service_ID"));
                    maServiceVO.setLocationID(rs.getInt("Location_ID"));                    
                    maServiceVO.setServiceName(rs.getString("Service_Name"));
                    maServiceVO.setServiceType(rs.getString("Service_Type_Name"));
                    log.debug("==========done with VendorDAOimpl.java (service)===========");

                } 

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            log.debug(e.getMessage());
            throw new CoopCRSAPIException(e.getMessage(), " VendorDAOimpl", "getAddServices", 500);
        } finally {
            closeConnections("getAddServices");
        }
        log.debug("&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&");
        log.debug("==========finsh===========");
        return results;

    }
```

Comment: prepare your question to have as little code as posible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see anything out of whack there. If there a reason you don't have this in a stored procedure instead of pass through sql? I did notice you didn't put square brackets around your final join but that shouldn't make any difference.

Here is your query after stripping off all the extra string parts for java.

```
SELECT  s.Service_ID  
    , s.[Location_ID]  
    , COALESCE(st.[Service_Type_Name], s.[Service_Name]) AS Service_name 
    , st.Service_Type_Name 
FROM [WebApp].[dbo].[Services] s 
join [WebApp].[dbo].[ServiceTypes] st on s.Service_Type = st.Service_Type_ID 
join [WebApp].[dbo].[Locations] l on s.Location_ID = l.Location_ID  
where s.Deleted = 0  
ORDER BY Location_ID;
```